# Why are MD5 hashes for the same data different on Linux and Windows?

Tags: perl, md5

Here's the workflow.

1. Client uploads an XML file and a checksum MD5 file to our FTP.
2. The Perl server copies the file from the FTP server.
3. The Perl server runs its own MD5 check on the XML file and then compares it to the value in the MD5 file.

The two MD5 hashes never match.  But, when I copy the XML file to my windows machine and run the same Perl script running in Windows, I get the same answer as their MD5 file.

Can anyone tell me what’s going on?

Here’s the script I am using to compute the MD5 hash.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Digest::MD5;
my $fname = "MarketPricePoint_2013_07_16_1500.xml";
open (my $fh, '<', $fname) or die "Can't open '$fname': $!";
binmode ($fh);
my $hash = Digest::MD5->new->addfile($fh)->hexdigest;
print $hash;
```

Comment: How is the file transmitted with FTP? binary or text mode? the latter changes line endings, and thus the checksum

Comment: Is the end-of-line (*i.e.*, `"\r\n"` versus `"\n"`) convention the same on both sides? Remember that ascii mode in FTP performs this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

ASCII mode is a common default for FTP servers that performs silent translation of line endings. If always transferring in binary mode is not an option, consider normalizing the line endings, as in the following.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Digest::MD5;

my $fname = "MarketPricePoint_2013_07_16_1500.xml";
open (my $fh, '<', $fname) or die "$0: open $fname: $!";
binmode ($fh) or die "$0: binmode: $!";;

(my $data = do { local $/; <$fh> }) =~ s/\r\n/\n/g;

my $hash = Digest::MD5->new->add($data)->hexdigest;
print $hash, "\n";
```